# user_register hook does not trigger the action required

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some custom code to connect subscription level from ultimate membership pro subscriptions with bookly customer groups.
The code is supposed to update info every 5 minuites and upon registration.
The problem is that while I can fetch the data and the 5 minuites cron wroks and updates data to bookly, the user_register does not get trigured upon registration.
FYI _ I am using code snipets and not adding the code in functions.php.

what could the problem be?

```
function get_all_users_from_ultimate_membership_pro() {
    $membership_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    $all_users = array();

    foreach ($membership_ids as $membership_id) {
        // Build the API URL with the specific membership ID
        $api_url = 'https://caterlinks.com/?ihc_action=api-gate&ihch=APiÍ-Key&action=get_level_users&lid=' . $membership_id;

        // Perform the API call
        $response = wp_remote_get($api_url);

        // Process the API response and add users to the result array with membership IDs
        if (!is_wp_error($response) && $response['response']['code'] === 200) {
            $data = json_decode($response['body'], true);
            if (isset($data['response']) && is_array($data['response'])) {
                foreach ($data['response'] as $user) {
                    $user['membership_id'] = $membership_id; // Add membership ID to user data
                    $all_users[] = $user; // Add the user to the result array
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_users;
}

/*
function display_synced_data_shortcode() {
    // Call the function and get the array of users
    $users = get_all_users_from_ultimate_membership_pro();

    // Print the array using print_r()
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($users);
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_shortcode('display_synced_data', 'display_synced_data_shortcode');
*/


// 1. Schedule periodic synchronization using WordPress cron
// Custom cron interval for 5 minutes
function add_5_minutes_cron_interval($schedules) {
    $schedules['5_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300, // 5 minutes in seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 5 Minutes User Update')
    );
    return $schedules;
}

add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_5_minutes_cron_interval');

// 2. Schedule periodic synchronization using WordPress cron every 5 minutes
if (!wp_next_scheduled('periodic_bookly_sync')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '5_minutes', 'periodic_bookly_sync');
}



// 3. Synchronize subscriptions to Bookly customer groups
function sync_subscriptions_to_bookly_groups() {
    // Get all users from Ultimate Membership Pro API
    $all_users = get_all_users_from_ultimate_membership_pro();
    $output = '';

    // Use print_r() to store the data
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    print_r($all_users);
    $output .= ob_get_clean(); // Capture the output and store it in $output

    foreach ($all_users as $user) {
        $user_id = isset($user['user_id']) ? $user['user_id'] : ''; // Check if 'user_id' index exists
        $membership_id = isset($user['membership_id']) ? $user['membership_id'] : ''; // Check if 'membership_id' index exists
        $username = isset($user['username']) ? $user['username'] : ''; // Check if 'username' index exists

        // Debug: Append values to the output to check if they are correct
        $output .= 'User ID: ' . $user_id . ', Membership ID: ' . $membership_id . ', Username: ' . $username . '<br>';

        // 4. Assign Bookly Group IDs based on Ultimate Membership Pro Membership IDs
        $bookly_group_id = 1;
        if ($membership_id === 1 || $membership_id === 3) {
            $bookly_group_id = 1;
        } elseif ($membership_id === 2 || $membership_id === 4) {
            $bookly_group_id = 2;
        } 

        // Debug: Append selected Bookly Group ID to the output
        $output .= 'Selected Bookly Group ID: ' . $bookly_group_id . '<br>';

        // 5. Update Bookly customer group ID and username
        update_bookly_group_for_user($user_id, $bookly_group_id, $username);
    }

    // Log the output to check the values
    error_log($output);
}

add_action('periodic_bookly_sync', 'sync_subscriptions_to_bookly_groups');
//Run bookly customer syncronisation upon user resgistration.
add_action('user_register', 'sync_subscriptions_to_bookly_groups');



/*
function display_synced_data_shortcode() {
    $data = sync_subscriptions_to_bookly_groups();
    return '<pre>' . $data . '</pre>';
}
add_shortcode('display_synced_data', 'display_synced_data_shortcode');
*/




function update_bookly_group_for_user($user_id, $bookly_group_id, $username) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'bookly_customers';

    // Check if the customer exists in the Bookly database
    $customer = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $customer_table WHERE wp_user_id = %d", $user_id)
    );

    if ($customer) {        $updated = $wpdb->update(
            $customer_table,
            array('group_id' => $bookly_group_id, 'full_name' => $username),
            array('wp_user_id' => $user_id)
        );

        return $updated !== false; // Return true if the update was successful
    } else {
        // Customer does not exist, insert a new record
        $inserted = $wpdb->insert(
            $customer_table,
            array('wp_user_id' => $user_id, 'group_id' => $bookly_group_id, 'full_name' => $username),
            array('%d', '%d', '%s') // '%s' is used for the username as it's a string
        );

        return $inserted !== false; // Return true if the insert was successfull
    }
}
```